# Reativar form ao fechamento de outro

Tags: c++, winforms, c++11

Eu tenho um *form* principal e desse form eu clico em um botão e abre outro *form*, ai quando eu abro este outro form eu desativo o principal, até aí tudo bem, então eu queria que quando o usuário fechasse o segundo *form*, o principal voltasse a funcionar normalmente. Gostaria de fazer isso usando o evento `FormClosed` no segundo *form*, então como vou reativar o primeiro *form* no código do segundo?

Essa é a parte do código que abre o form

```
if (numbersandletter->IsMatch(txta->Text) && (Convert::ToDouble(a) * letra) > 0){

                Mat::Mat1^ mat1 = gcnew Mat1();
                mat1->Show();
                this->Enabled = false;

    }
```

Abro o *form* secundário e desativo o principal.

Comment: É a primeira pessoa que vejo usando WinForms c/ C++ :)

Comment: É Normal Usar O Que ?

Comment: C# e muito eventualmente VB.Net.

Comment: Qual A Vantagem ?

Comment: São linguagens bem mais fáceis e com mais apoio da Microsoft pelo menos para esta tecnologia (se bem que a tecnologia já está quase abandonada também).

Comment: Bom Eu Prefiro Desempenho Do Que Uma Linguagem Fácil, Uma Opinião Apenas, E Quanto A Isso Da Microsoft, Realmente É Muito Chato.

Comment: Como você está usando o .Net o desempenho do C++ não é tudo isto. E desempenho para aplicação GUI? Qualquer GUI é tão lenta, mas tão lenta que pode escolher a linguagem que for, não fará diferença. O que o pessoal faz é pegar os trechos que realmente precisam de performance e otimizar, eventualmente até em outro linguagem mais rápida. Mas para a maioria das coisas você não vai encontrar muito mais performance em C++/CLI do que em C#. Você está procurando a performance sem uma justificativa para ele. Acredito que você ainda seja novato.

Comment: Adicione à pergunta seu código relevante para tentarmos ajudá-lo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente este código:

```
if (numbersandletter->IsMatch(txta->Text) && (Convert::ToDouble(a) * letra) > 0){
            Mat::Mat1^ mat1 = gcnew Mat1();
            this->Enabled = false;  // Desnecessário
            mat1->ShowDialog(this); // O ShowDialog ficara aguardando o fechamento do form
            this->Enabled = true;   // Esta linha será executada após o fechamento do form
            this->Focus();       

}
```

Comment: Excelente, já tinha pensando em Dialog mas não sei pq n fiz :/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o mesmo código no form secundário, porém não creio que você consiga fazê-lo diretamente no formClosed, mas sim no FormClosing, pois este evento é disparado antes do formulário fechar.

A diferença de um código para o outro é que ao invés de utilizar

```
mat1->show();
this->Enabled = False;
```

Você teria que usar um comando do tipo:

```
form1->show();
form1->Enabled = True;
this->Enabled = False;
```

Seguindo a sequencia de abertura e ativação dos formulários.

Um outro modo, que envolveria um pouco mais de trabalho, é criar um "Cadastro" de variáveis globais indicando status, um array global [form,status] a ser verificado a cada inicio de formulário, onde somente os formulários alterariam o valor "Status" do respectivo "Form".

De qualquer forma acredito que ambas as soluções sejam validas.